# How do I prevent a fixed footer from covering up the content of a JQuery Mobile page?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, footer

I have a JQuery Mobile app, but I have my own complicated footer div that stays on the bottom of the page no matter what (position: fixed), and is not controlled by JQM (its not a data-role="footer", but is instead in its own div section, so I only have one for the entire app)

The problem is this footer is covering up the last few lines of the content if its long enough.

I would think a solution would be to somehow add padding of the size of the footer so the scroll bar would work correctly to show the last lines of the content.

So for this example, I have a content that is n lines long. When I scroll to the bottom, I would like to see the last lines of this file above the footer. Instead, I don't see the last few lines as they are covered up by the footer.

Desire:

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|                                     |
|    Header                           |
|                                     |
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Content Line n-3
Content Line n-2
Content Line n-1
Content Line n
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|                                      |
|  Footer                              |
```

But I'm Getting

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|                                     |
|    Header                           |
|                                     |
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Content Line n-6
Content Line n-5
Content Line n-4
Content Line n-3
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|                                      |
|  Footer                              |
```

**Update:**

Thanks to the responses, it led me down the right track.

I added the following to my .css file:

```
.ui-content
{
    margin-bottom: 251px; /* The height of the footer */
}
```

The problem with this is if the footer height changes (different font, or a line gets added) then this won't automatically update. I think I can do some Javascript to fix this.

**Update 2:**

I made it dynamic by implementing the following:

```
.bind('pageinit', function () {
    $(".ui-content").css('margin-bottom', $('#footer').height());
})
```

Comment: You're on the right track with `...add padding of the size of the footer...`. Try surrounding your content in a `div` and give it a `margin-bottom` equal to the height of your footer.

Answer (score 0):

Because I assume your footer is in a layer above the content they can't specifically make room for each other so I would recommend that you place some filler the shape of the footer at the end of your content. This can be accomplish as MrOBrian said by placing your content in a `<div  margin-bottom=footer height>`, using `<br />`, creating a footer shaped `<div>` or many other options you many find.